# Doubling breaks after removing <br> and leaving just text

Tags: javascript, html, text, line-breaks

After I perform following:

```
var noTags = document.createElement("DIV");
noTags.innerHTML = html;
noTags.textContent // <- I put this into any textarea
```

and this text:

```
text test <br><br> this text
```

Turns into this text:

```
text test 


this text
```

Some how I get extra break. And they just keep on comming every time I do the above javascript. Please help :-(

Comment: Am unable to replicate i.. http://jsfiddle.net/GFyuP/

Comment: @Cybernate try the HTML in my answer below.  I too was unable to duplicate exactly, but did get different results in IE7 vs. Firefox 3.6.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign html to the innerHTML property the browser will interpret that string based on the DOCTYPE set for the page.  You will be at the mercy of the parser that the browser implemented for that DOCTYPE and the browser's implementation of said standard; read another way, "you will be guaranteed to get different results on different browsers".

That being said each browser will interpret the following HTML slightly differently.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing textcontent</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<textarea id="onlyText" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*//*---->*/
var html = "text text <br><br> text";
var noTags = document.createElement("DIV");
noTags.innerHTML = html;

// Retrieve text from html
var textContent = "";
var oe = document.getElementById("onlyText");

if (oe.innerText == undefined) {
    textContent = noTags.textContent;
} else {
    textContent = noTags.innerText;
}

alert("DEBUG: textContent = " + textContent);


oe.innerHTML = textContent;

/*--*//*]]>*/
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Welcome to the interwebs.  Your code will vary.

Answer (score 0):

You have two breaks in there, why wouldn't you expect there to be two lines?

Breaks are usually done as a single closed tag, too. `<br/>` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: In XHTML, one must use `<br/>` (or `<br></br>`, but that's silly ;-). But in HTML, `<br>` has no end tag. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2.1

Comment: @Dan Breslau is correct.  The OP was noticing an EXTRA newline in his text output that he could not explain.